# Laravel 4 not returning one-to-many

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

This seems like a no brainer but for some reason I can't figure out what is going on here. I have Laravel app using the repository design pattern. I have a Departments Model and a Stations Model.

```
class Teacher extends \Eloquent {
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('AppName\Models\Student');
    }
}

class Student extends \Eloquent {
 use SoftDeletingTrait;

public function teacher()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\AppName\Models\Teacher');
    }
}
```

I have a FK from the teacher_id field in the students table to the id field in the teachers table. I have to  pass 'id' as the second param or I get a teacher_id column not found in teachers table sql exception.

When I return

```
Teacher::find($teacher_id)->students;
```

from the repository it gives me the row from the teachers table just as if I had returned

```
Teacher::find($teacher_id);
```

What am i missing here? Seems like it should work.. why is even looking for a teacher_id in the teachers table and not the students table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I can't believe how much time I've spent on this and the answer was so obvious. I accidentally had my $table var set to 'teachers' in the Student model.